# Vim line range based on a search

Tags: vim

How would I do something like the following in vim?

```
:1,/time s/import/new/g
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
- `:1,` from line 1...
- `/time` until the (first) match of the word 'time'
- `s/import/new/g` substitute the word 'import' with the word 'new'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is almost correct.  You need to use a second slash after your pattern to distinguish the end of your pattern from what comes next.  So it would look like this:

```
:1,/time/ s/import/new/g
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the search offset feature.
This command *excludes* the line containing 'time'

```
    1,/time/-1s/import/new/g
```

The -1 here means 1 line *up* from the first line containing 'time'.

`:help search-offset`

Comment: I see, thanks for that tip on it being exclusive/inclusive with the `+1` or `-1`.